# jQuery Scroll only happens after first select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mouseevent, onchange

I have an odd problem with my jQuery. I have an element that I want to toggleTo once a dropdown option has been selected. The odd thing is that it only triggers AFTER the first time it has been changed. It will not scroll to the right element on the first change, but subsequent changes after that!

Why is it ignoring the first one? Maybe I selected the wrong event attribute? I have tried other ones such as mouseleave() with no luck. I feel like I have used the right attribute because I want it to scroll when the user selects or changes the dropdown value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Please find my code attached below:

**home.php**

```
  //SCROLL TO TRANSFER GUIDE ON click

      $("#major").on('change',function() {
        $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#scrollHere").offset().top
      }, 1000);
      });
```

**major.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'db_connect_clearmaze.php';
?>

<body>

<h3 align="center" class="header whitetext">Choose Your Major</h3>

<?php
  $uni = trim($_GET['uni']);
  $_SESSION['uni'] = $uni;
  $cc = $_SESSION['cc'];
?>


<form align="center">
    <select id = "major" class="dropbtn" onmouseover="DropListMajor()"
  onmouseout="this.size=1;" onchange="loadTransferGuide(this.value,'<?php echo $uni; ?>','<?php echo $cc; ?>')">
    <?php
    echo '<option value=""> Select Your Major </option>';
        $query = $db -> query("SELECT major FROM majors WHERE university = '".$uni."';");
        while($row = $query -> fetch()){
            echo '<option value = "'.$row['major'].'">' ?>
            <?php echo $row['major'].'<br>' ?> <?php '</option>';
        }

     ?>

    </select>

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Is it a possibility that `$("#major").on('change',function()` is inside `loadTransferGuide(...)` ?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Great suggestion but unfortunately didn't work for me :( For a second I thought you had something! Any other ideas?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Just tried another positioning of the function elsewhere in the document and it works perfectly! Thank you SO MUCH!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `change` event handler `$("#major").on('change',function(){...}` was defined inside another `change` handler...

So on 1st change, the first inline handler defined the second handler.

That is why it was not firing on the first change.

I guessed it because it was fitting the behavior described...
but also because of this comment `//SCROLL TO TRANSFER GUIDE ON click`.

;)